# How do I disable assertions for the entire project?

Tags: delphi, assert

I have some code in Delphi that has `Assert` statements all over it. I know that there is a compiler directive `{$C-}`, but there are too many units to add it to. Is there a way to have it done by the compiler command line or somewhere in the dpr file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$C-` from the command line as well, or configure it in 'Project->Options->Compiler' from the IDE (which configures it in the .dproj file).

There's a list of command line switches and options available by typing `dcc32` from the command line. It can be redirected to a text file using command redirection (as in `dcc32 > dccCommands.txt`), which produces the following output with XE5's version of dcc32:

```
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 26.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2013 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.

Syntax: dcc32 [options] filename [options]

  -A<unit>=<alias> = Set unit alias
  -B = Build all units             
  -CC = Console target             
  -CG = GUI target                 
  -D<syms> = Define conditionals   
  -E<path> = EXE/DLL output directory
  -F<offset> = Find error          
  -GD = Detailed map file          
  -GP = Map file with publics      
  -GS = Map file with segments     
  -H = Output hint messages        
  -I<paths> = Include directories  
  -J = Generate .obj file          
  -JPHNE = Generate C++ .obj file, .hpp file, in namespace, export all
  -JL = Generate package .lib, .bpi, and all .hpp files for C++
  -K<addr> = Set image base addr   
  -LE<path> = package .bpl output directory
  -LN<path> = package .dcp output directory
  -LU<package> = Use package       
  -M = Make modified units         
  -NU<path> = unit .dcu output directory
  -NH<path> = unit .hpp output directory
  -NO<path> = unit .obj output directory
  -NB<path> = unit .bpi output directory
  -NX<path> = unit .xml output directory
  -NS<namespaces> = Namespace search path
  -O<paths> = Object directories   
  -P = look for 8.3 file names also
  -Q = Quiet compile               
  -R<paths> = Resource directories 
  -TX<ext> = Output name extension 
  -U<paths> = Unit directories     
  -V = Debug information in EXE    
  -VR = Generate remote debug (RSM)
  -VT = Debug information in TDS   
  -VN = TDS symbols in namespace   
  -W[+|-|^][warn_id] = Output warning messages
  -Z = Output 'never build' DCPs   
  -$<dir> = Compiler directive     
  --help = Show this help screen   
  --version = Show name and version
  --codepage:<cp> = specify source file encoding
  --default-namespace:<namespace> = set namespace
  --depends = output unit dependency information
  --doc = output XML documentation 
  --drc = output resource string .drc file
  --no-config = do not load default dcc32.cfg file
  --description:<string> = set executable description
  --inline:{on|off|auto} = function inlining control
  --legacy-ifend = allow legacy $IFEND directive
  --zero-based-strings[+|-] = strings are indexed starting at 0
  --peflags:<flags> = set extra PE Header flags field
  --peoptflags:<flags> = set extra PE Header optional flags field
  --peosversion:<major>.<minor> = set OS Version fields in PE Header (default: 5.0)
  --pesubsysversion:<major>.<minor> = set Subsystem Version fields in PE Header (default: 5.0)
  --peuserversion:<major>.<minor> = set User Version fields in PE Header (default: 0.0)
Compiler switches: -$<letter><state> (defaults are shown below)
  A8  Aligned record fields         
  B-  Full boolean Evaluation       
  C+  Evaluate assertions at runtime
  D+  Debug information             
  G+  Use imported data references  
  H+  Use long strings by default   
  I+  I/O checking                  
  J-  Writeable structured consts   
  L+  Local debug symbols           
  M-  Runtime type info             
  O+  Optimization                  
  P+  Open string params            
  Q-  Integer overflow checking     
  R-  Range checking                
  T-  Typed @ operator              
  U-  Pentium(tm)-safe divide       
  V+  Strict var-strings            
  W-  Generate stack frames         
  X+  Extended syntax               
  Y+  Symbol reference info         
  Z1  Minimum size of enum types    
Stack size: -$M<minStackSize[,maxStackSize]> (default 16384,1048576)
```

Comment: Still assertions may be re-enabled later locally, in some particular units sources... But it seems there is nothing can be done about it except using some pre-processor